# Migrating Silverlight MVVM to ASP.NET Web Forms or ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, silverlight, mvvm

We have application have been written in Silverlight using MVVM pattern. We need to move some pages into ASP.NET. If you have some experience in this field or any ideas please write. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's well written MVVM it's probably an ideal candidate for ASP.net MVC, within minimal back end changes.